# How to use OAuth2 using PHP cURL

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

I've written below code in PHP.

```
<?php
$user = "AB123456";
$api_secret = "ghjfvnvbvnmvmnnbvbnvnbvbnv3345vbnvbnvnbv3bv2bnv";
$redirect_url = "https://ant.aliceblueonline.com/plugin/callback";
$code = "azvUgu6BPhIbe4yAQALBl";
$url = "https://ant.aliceblueonline.com/oauth2/token?client_id=".$user."&client_secret=".$api_secret."&grant_type=authorization_code&code=".$code."&redirect_uri=".$redirect_url."&authorization_response=".$redirect_url;


$session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("client_id=" => $user, "client_secret" => $api_secret, "grant_type" => "authorization_code", "code" => $code, "redirect_uri" => $redirect_url));
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($user.":".$api_secret));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$r = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

echo $r;

?>
```

But it is giving below error whereas grant_type is already there in request parameter -

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed","error_hint":"Request parameter \"grant_type\"\" is missing","status_code":400}
```

Please help.

Comment: Why do you have `=` after `client_id` in the first key? What happens if you remove that?

Comment: It was designed by them (AliceBlue). I checked their Python code and there it was there. If you remove it nothing will happen as the request has to be sent by POST.

Comment: In Python it is working fine. 
r = requests.session()
params = {"cliend_id": user, 'client_secret' : api_secret, 'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'code': code, 'redirect_uri': redirect_url}
resp = r.post(url, auth=(user, api_secret), data=params)
print(resp.text)

Comment: resp = r.post(url, auth=(user, api_secret), data=params) - This line I need to implement in PHP which I'm unable to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove client_id and client_secret from CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS as they are sent using Authentication header.

Updated cURL CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS line as mentioned below.

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=authorization_code&code=".$code."&redirect_uri=".$redirect_url);
```